# Protection of insulators on overhead transmission lines

Tags: transmission-line, insulator

Protection of insulators on overhead transmission lines.

Is an arcing horn the same thing as a coordination gap?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they both serve the same purpose.  To allow flashover current to flow across their air gap instead of along the surface of the protected insulation.

See the [Arcing horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcing_horns) wiki page.